Subset by value in columnA and get the value in a columnC that corresponds to the maximum value row of columnB in R? Automate this using loop
The title is rather confusing (apologies), but I will try to explain it here.
I have a dataset with multiple names of individuals, the number of coffees they have had on a particular day of the week, and the corresponding day of the week in 3 columns
For e.g.

What I want as an output, is the 'day' (column 3), when Tom, Mary, and John have the 'maximum' amount of coffee. i.e. Tom - Monday, Mary - Friday, John - Monday as a table.
x=data.frame(read.csv(file.choose()))
tom=subset(x,x$Name=="Tom")
tom.max=max(tom)
tom$Day[which.max(tom$Coffees)]


I could do this for one name, but struggling to use a loop to do it for all the names together, so I wouldn't have to repeat it for every single name in a bigger dataset. I want the output to look something like this

Any help would be appreciated.

This can be achieved easily with the dplyr package. Please note that posting screen-shot images of your data is frowned upon - better to cut-and-paste the actual numbers (as text) or use the dput() function.
df <- read.table(sep="", header=TRUE, text=c("
Name   Coffees  Day
Tom      2      Monday
Tom      1      Wednesday
Mary     3      Friday
Tom      2      Thursday
John     3      Monday
Tom      4      Monday
Mary     5      Tuesday
Tom      6      Friday
John     1      Saturday
"))

df
#>   Name Coffees       Day
#> 1  Tom       2    Monday
#> 2  Tom       1 Wednesday
#> 3 Mary       3    Friday
#> 4  Tom       2  Thursday
#> 5 John       3    Monday
#> 6  Tom       4    Monday
#> 7 Mary       5   Tuesday
#> 8  Tom       6    Friday
#> 9 John       1  Saturday

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Coffees), .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  slice_head(n=1)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Groups:   Name [3]
#>   Name  Coffees Day    
#>   <chr>   <int> <chr>  
#> 1 John        3 Monday 
#> 2 Mary        5 Tuesday
#> 3 Tom         6 Friday

Created on 2024-05-15 with reprex v2.1.0

Update:
Effective way:
dplyr::slice_max(df, Coffees, by=Name)

  Name Coffees    Day
1  Tom       6 Monday
2 Mary       3 Friday
3 John       5 Monday

#test:
library(microbenchmark)

mbm = microbenchmark(
tarjae = dplyr::slice_max(df, Coffees, by=Name),
DavOz = df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Coffees), .by_group=TRUE) %>% 
  slice_head(n=1),
times=50
)
mbm
autoplot(mbm)


First answer:
Here is a dplyr solution:
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  slice_max(Coffees, by=Name) %>% 
  # select(-Coffees)

 Name    Day
1  Tom Monday
2 Mary Friday
3 John Monday

data:
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Tom", "Tom", "Mary", "Tom", "John", "Tom", "Mary", "Tom", "John"),
  Coffees = c(2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3),
  Day = c("Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Thursday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday", "Saturday")
)

Here is the base R equivalent:
max_df <- merge(df, aggregate(Coffees ~ Name, df, max), by = c("Name", "Coffees"))
max_df[, c("Name", "Day")]


I love this short code,  concise and efficient,+1!

You can use subset + ave in base R
> subset(df, ave(Coffees, Name, FUN = max) == Coffees)
  Name Coffees    Day
3 Mary       3 Friday
5 John       5 Monday
6  Tom       6 Monday

